# sqlite file gets picked up by the xcode simulator but not the ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, core-data

I had a sqlite file which was working fine on the simulator and the device.
Under my app folder on the mac, I can also see the file - coredata.sqlite.

I created a new coredata.sqlite. After this, I had to copy it over to the paths which were different for different targets (iphone 5 vs 6 vs 6+) and looked along the lines of :

```
    .../Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/26292D7B-5001-497E-B23B-99455953F5F4/data/Containers/Data/Application/64849BCC-B86B-45DE-818F-3E67346C4893/Documents/
```

Just copying over the new sqlite to the apps folder where the old sqlite was present did not work. Copying it to the above mentioned folders fixed it for the simulator.

Now, when I connect to my ios device though, it cant find the new sqlite. If I copy back the old sqlite to the apps folder, it still works but copying the new one to the apps folder, the various destinations for the simulator etc has no effect on the ios device.
Displaying the path where it is looking at shows :

```
    /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/80302FBA-6D45-4843-A891-E10A7ED4D445/Documents/CoreData.sqlite
```

Any help on where the device is picking the sqlite from? Since it works on the simulator and the older one works on the device also, the code seems ok. What can I do to get it to pick my new sqlite?

Comment: I found the issue. When I copied over the file,it only had rw persmissions but not execute. Changing the permissions to rwx fixed it. Should have checked that first, duh! Keeping the question open though because looking at Gandalf's response, there seems to be a proper way of doing this which I overlooked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Device will pick the files from `mainBundle`. While doing database related functionality we copy the db files from mainBundle to `DocumentDirectory`, so that it becomes editable.

What you did was that you manually copied the sqlite file to the app data document folder. You should actually add the file to specific target and then it will copy the file during build process.

Your new `coredata.sqlite` file is not attached to any target. Check inside build phases and see if it is there, otherwise add it. Also you should not have two files with same name inside the bundle, so remove the previous file from target.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Giving the file execute permissions fixed it but it may not have been the right way. Where in the build settings should I add it? I did remove the old file, there is no duplication.

Comment: Sorry, i meant _Build Phases_ not _Build Settings_. Click on project file(the blue one) inside project pane(left side where class files are shown), then click on the targets, then you will see some tab options like General, info, Build Settings, Build Phases etc. Check inside __Copy Bundle Resource Files__